# Hardware calibration for Eizo Monitor on Linux / Ubuntu without ColorNavigator?

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, linux

I have a monitor that supports hardware calibration (*Eizo CG223w*). Eizo offers a tool called *ColorNavigator* to get the calibration done. Unfortunately *ColorNavigator* does not support Linux and I'm using Ubuntu...

Does anyone know if there is an alternative way to get the hardware calibration done in Linux / Ubuntu using a *spyder3Elite*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about Linux software and is probably a better fit over at [softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you don't want it here, please don't close it. I would still love to see this problem solved and I'm surly not alone. May be it can be moved to 'Ask Ubuntu' SE instead?

Answer (score 3):

According to Eizo, this is not possible.

I've had a lengthy conversation with a very friendly Eizo technican in
October 2016, concerning the monitor CS2420.  I would expect this to
hold true for all their current displays.

The result was as follows:

- Eizo has (at that time) a Linux version of their ColorNavigator.
  But they do not publish that software on their website, because
  they do not guarantee that it's working (yes, that's what he
  said).
- On request, Eizo Support sent me a download link [1] which looked
  rather ad-hoc.  I failed to get this working on ArchLinux, error
  messages were useless.
- There is no documentation and no support.
- There is no other means to access hardware calibration on the Eizo
  CS2420, because the interface is deliberately kept secret.

Due to this, I've decided to get a non-Eizo monitor (after more than
a decade of being their customer).

---

[1] Yes, that is the Link they actually sent me:
    https://lfstorage.eizo.com/link/dv8Yu3PJcL7uIloIIzyi3i

Answer (score 2):

1. Check [Argyll CMS/DisplayCal](http://displaycal.net). I think it does *not* support HW calibration, though.
2. Check the [color management forum at luminous-landscape.com](http://forum.luminous-landscape.com/index.php?board=45.0). Best source of information about display calibration (hardware or not) to my knowledge.
3. Contact EIZO...

Answer (score 2):

Eizo ColorNavigator 6 and ColorNavigator NX are available for Linux but only for Red Hat Enterprise Linux/CentOS 6. Eizo mention Linux here and there on their website but they do not provide direct download link anywhere. Eizo support however gave me proper download link without any questions.

Provided package is not 'ad-hoc' but proper installation script which does all it needs to install ColorNavigator. The ColorNavigator itself works perfectly fine after installation on CentOS 6.8 x86_64 on bare metal and VirtualBox. I was able to calibrate Eizo monitor completely with X-Rite iDisplay Pro.

I do not know if Eizo gives any support.

I tried to launch CN6 on Ubuntu 16.04 x64_84 but it fails because CN6 is 32bit app and there are unresolved differences between RH and Ubuntu libraries.

I like the CN6 very much . The calibration is very easy and quick.
Hopefully Eizo will consider update/rebuild CN6 to extend their Linux support.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a windows computer you can profile the monitor on that. It will create a standard ICC profile as well as calibrate the Eizo internally to that profile. Then just copy the profile you made that matches the internally calibrated monitor to your Linux machine and move the monitor to it as well. Assign the profile as your active monitor's profile. Since the monitor has already been internally calibrated with ColorNavigator it will work with the copied profile.